# NTPd giving the wrong time

Tags: fedora-14, ntp

Running `ntpd -q` on a Fedora 14 VM gives the wrong time. I'm in the UK so my time should be UTC+1, but instead it's 6 minutes behind what it should be.

Anyone know why this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: There's a useful (and comprehensive) White Paper on timekeeping in VMs: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware%5Ftimekeeping.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This previous answer [Ubuntu time issues](https://superuser.com/questions/255939/ubuntu-time-issues) recommends against running ntpd in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

The time on the server hosting your VM is off.  Fix it and check again. Disable ntpd on your virtual machine, and sync to the virtual hardware clock.